# React Native: Is there a native module for accessing and scanning files (e.g. audio files) in sdcard of android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

There are some components can access `DocumentDirectory`, like [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs).

But I really need one component can access and scan the media files in the whole sdcard.

Is there some good choices? Or some guid for me to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob). It supports file access & scan the media files.